# Redirect after Date and time symfony

Tags: php, html, symfony

Am working on my first Symfony site and I need to redirect the site from /index to /final when a certatin date/time is reached. Is there a way of doing that?

This is what I have so far:

```js
      $now = (new \DateTime())->format('Y-m-d H:i');
        $deadline = "2019-07-26 09:35"
        if ($now > $deadline) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('final');
        }
```

but Symfony gives me this error:

> syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

Comment: It miss an `;` on line `$deadline = "2019-07-26 09:35"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check on your `index` method the date then use [Symfony redirection](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#redirecting)

EDIT:

`

```
 $now = new \DateTime();
 //it's better to compare date time object
 $deadline = new \DateTime("2019-07-26 09:35");
 if ($now > $deadline) {
    return $this->redirectToRoute('final');
 }
```

`

Comment: It say that `final` route doesn't exist. Maybe you not create the route with the name like [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#creating-routes):

`@Route("/final", name="final")`